# Security of a MAC

Tags: mac

Let $(Mac, Vrfy)$ be a safe defined $MAC$ over $(K,M,T)$ where $ M = \{0,1\}^n$ and $T = \{0,1\}^{128}$.
Is the following $MAC$ safe? Show your proof.

$Mac'(k,m) = Mac(k, m ⊕ m)$

$Vrfy'(k,m,t) = Vrfy(k,m ⊕ m, t)$

I have no idea how I can prove this, please help.
How would I go about proving this? Thank you for your help.

EDIT:

So I tried something, I don't know if it is correct tho, can you please confirm it?

So, because $m⊕m = 0$ the $Mac'(k,m) = Mac(k, m ⊕ m)$ produces a tag $t$ for $0$ and $k$ key, it means that $Vrfy'(k,m,t) = Vrfy(k,m ⊕ m, t)$ will always return $true$ because it verifies the same $m⊕m$ message which is $0$ and $k$ key, which is equal to the returned $t$ ? is that correct?

Comment: Is there an efficient attack on it? ​ If no, why? ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: Hint: what is $m \oplus m$?

Comment: @poncho the sent message XOR sent message ? What exactly do you mean by that question? Sorry, I really don't understand what I have to be looking for, I am a newbie and I have an exam in 3 days and I need to understand this type of problems.

Comment: And when you xor anything with itself, what is the result?

Comment: @poncho XOR-ing something with itself gives you $0$, right? so $m⊕m = 0$ ? Is that right ?

Comment: And what would that imply about $Mac'$?

Comment: @poncho I edited the question with my attempt to solve the problem, have a look at it and say if it is correct, thank you.

Comment: what you wrote is correct (at the moment), but it is not the full answer. I would also add another question to help you: What is a *safe MAC* ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have the right idea; here's a more formal way of saying it.

A MAC is secure if an attacker who, given an Oracle that can generate MACs for messages (with a secret random key), cannot (with nontrivial probability) generate a valid Message, MAC pair for a Message he has not queried the Oracle.

For $Mac'$, what the attacker could do is select a message (for example, the string $0$), and query the Oracle for the corresponding tag $T$.  So, the attacker knows that $0, T$ is a valid message/tag pair (but that doesn't count for the goal, as he asked for that message).

So, the attacker selects a different message for the same length (for example, the string $1$), and form the message pair $1, T$ (where $T$ is the tag he got previously).  As $Vrfy'(k, 1, T) = Vrfy(k, 1 \oplus 1, T) = Vrfy(k, 0 \oplus 0, T) = Vrfy'(k, 0, T)$ evaluates to true (as $0, T$ is a valid pair), so is $1, T$ as well (and so the attacker wins, as he has found the MAC for a message he didn't ask for)

Comment: I see now, wow I would have never thought using the previous tag with a new message to see if it evaluates true, amazing, I understand now, thank you!